# Find $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\binom{2k+1}{3}\frac{1}{2^{2(2k-1)}}\left[\binom{2k-2}{k-2}-\binom{2k-2}{k-1}\right]^2$.

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

While trying to compute the limit as $k\rightarrow \infty$ of the level 3 Energy Spectrum of the Majority Boolean Function, the following expression arises

$$\binom{2k+1}{3}\frac{1}{2^{2(2k-1)}}\left[\binom{2k-2}{k-2}-\binom{2k-2}{k-1}\right]^2.$$

Are there any tricks\bounds (non brute force) to compute this limit?

As $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{2k-2}{2j}=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\binom{2k-2}{2j-1}=2^{2k-3}$, my guess is that this limit is zero, but ignoring the term $-2\binom{2k-2}{k-2}\binom{2k-2}{k-1}$ and using that $\binom{2k-2}{j}\leq 2^{2k-3}$ is not sharp enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure, if this qualifies as brute force, so you be the judge of that. Try to prove the identity $\binom{2n}{n-1}-\binom{2n}{n}=-\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ to simplify the expression between the parantheses. Then using that $\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ for n large enough (hint: Stirling's approximation) you can calculate the limit.

Answer (score 2):

**Without a full simplification**

Start simplifying the expression $$y_k=\binom{2k+1}{3}\frac{1}{2^{2(2k-1)}}\left[\binom{2k-2}{k-2}-\binom{2k-2}{k-1}\right]^2$$ using
$$\binom{2k+1}{3}=\frac{1}{3} k (2 k-1) (2 k+1)$$
$$\binom{2k-2}{k-2}-\binom{2k-2}{k-1}=\frac{\Gamma (2 k-1)}{\Gamma (k-1) \Gamma (k+1)}-\frac{2^{2 k-2} \Gamma
   \left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (k)}$$ Now, start series expansions
$$A=\frac{\Gamma (2 k-1)}{\Gamma (k-1) \Gamma (k+1)}$$
$$\log(A)=k \log (4)-\frac{1}{2} \log (16 \pi  k)-\frac{5}{8 k}-\frac{3}{8 k^2}-\frac{55}{192
   k^3}-\frac{15}{64 k^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)$$

$$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{4^{k-1}}{\sqrt{k\pi } }\Bigg[1-\frac{5}{8 k}-\frac{23}{128 k^2}-\frac{95}{1024 k^3}-\frac{1701}{32768
   k^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right) \Bigg]$$

$$B=\frac{2^{2 k-2} \Gamma
   \left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (k)}$$
$$\log(B)=k \log (4)-\frac{1}{2} \log (16 \pi  k)+\frac{3}{8 k}+\frac{1}{8 k^2}+\frac{3}{64
   k^3}+\frac{1}{64 k^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)$$
$$B=e^{\log(B)}=\frac{4^{k-1}}{\sqrt{k\pi }}\Bigg[1+\frac{3}{8 k}+\frac{25}{128 k^2}+\frac{105}{1024 k^3}+\frac{1659}{32768
   k^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right) \Bigg]$$
$$(A-B)^2=4^{2 k} \left(\frac{1}{16 \pi  k^3}+\frac{3}{64 \pi  k^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)\right)$$
All of the above make
$$y_k=\frac{1}{3 \pi }\left(1+\frac{3}{4 k}+\frac{9}{32 k^2}+\frac{21}{128
   k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right) \right)$$

Much faster !

For a quick check
$$y_{10}=\frac{3929991065}{34359738368}\sim 0.1143778$$ while the truncated series expansion gives
$$y_{10}\sim \frac{137981}{384000 \pi }\sim 0.1143769$$

**With a full simplification**

Using the hint @user299843 gave in comments
$$A-B=-\frac{\Gamma (2 k-1)}{\Gamma (k) \Gamma (k+1)}$$ gives
$$y_k=\frac{1}{3} k (2 k-1) (2 k+1)\frac{1}{2^{2(2k-1)}}\Bigg[\frac{\Gamma (2 k-1)}{\Gamma (k) \Gamma (k+1)} \Bigg]^2$$ Take logarithms and use Stirling approximation and continue with Taylor
$$\log(y_k)=\log \left(\frac{1}{3 \pi }\right)+\frac{3}{4 k}+\frac{3}{32 k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)$$
$$y_k=e^{\log(y_k)}=\frac{1}{3 \pi }\left(1+\frac{3}{4 k}+\frac{9}{32 k^2}+\frac{21}{128
   k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right) \right)$$